# an error "has no member named"

Tags: c++

I have this snippet of the code

#### account.cpp

```
#include "account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  

using namespace std;

Account::Account(string firstName, string lastName, int id)
    : strFirstName(firstName), strLastName(lastName), nID(id) {}

void Account::printAccount(){
    cout << strFirstName;
}
```

#### account.h

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Account{
private:
    string strLastName;      //Client's last name
    string strFirstName;     //Client's first name
    int nID;                //Client's ID number
    int nLines;             //Number of lines related to account
    double lastBill;
public:
    Account(string firstName, string lastName, int id);
        void printAccount();
};
```

#### company.h

```
#ifndef CELLULAR_COMPANY_H
#define CELLULAR_COMPANY_H

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "account.h"

using namespace std;

class Company {
private:
    list<Account> listOfAccounts;
public:
    void addAccount(string firstName, string lastName, int id) {
        Account newAccount(firstName, lastName, id);
        listOfAccounts.push_back(newAccount);
    }

    void printAccounts(){
        for(list<Account>::iterator i = listOfAccounts.begin(); i != listOfAccounts.end(); ++i){
            i.printAccount;           //here bug
        }
    }
};


#endif // CELLULAR_COMPANY_H
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "cellularcompany.h"

int main(){
    Company newCompany;
    newCompany.addAccount("Pavel", "Nedved", 11111);
    newCompany.printAccounts();

    return 0;
}
```

can somebody please explain what does my error mean? thanks in advance (I have it in company.h see comment there)
 I have bug `'struct std::_List_iterator<Account>' has no member named 'printAccount'`

Comment: Posting the full compiler error output will help us tremendously.

Comment: Please give full error that you get.

Comment: Possibly your unnecessary use of long variable names and hungarian notation made the code less readable, and so hid the error from you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses after `printAccount()`. Otherwise, it's not a method call. Also, you need to use the `->` operator, since it's an iterator.

```
for(list<Account>::iterator i = listOfAccounts.begin();
    i != listOfAccounts.end(); ++i)
{ 
    i->printAccount();  // Note the ()!
    // This is equivalent to (*i).printAccount(); 
}
```

Comment: I did it now, but I have the same effect

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `i.printAccount;` to `i->printAccount();`